# How to embed a .ttf and .eot file as one font?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting my *font* compatible on all browsers. The `.ttf` file works on all browsers except *explorer*. Here is my current code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham;
  src: url("../Gotham-Book.eot"),
  src: url("../Gotham-Book.eot#iefix") format('embedded-opentype');
  src: url("../Gotham-Book.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have too many `src:` declarations, thus overriding the IE hacks with a new one. Browser sees only `tff` in your example.

You should have only two, the first being a separate one. Notice how the middle line with fonts has a `,` instead of `;` at the end and how there's no `src:` in the last oe.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham;
  src: url("../Gotham-Book.eot"),
  src: url("../Gotham-Book.eot#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
       url("../Gotham-Book.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: This did not work, I also tried: @font-face {
  font-family: Gotham;
  src: url("../Gotham-Book.eot"),
       url("../Gotham-Book.ttf") format("truetype");
}

Comment: Could it be a bad or invalid .eot file causing this? I used a random converter to get the file into an .eot.